# Delphi 2007 won't start: Type initializer exception

Tags: delphi

This suddenly happened today. PC rebooted probably due to Windows Update and now this:
[image]
I tried full uninstall/install of Delphi & .Net2.0 SDK but to no avail. 
I can't update to a newer one because one of my project components does not support Unicode. Delphi 7 won't run on Win10 and I think D2005&2006 depend on the same .net sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing regional settings from Russian (Ukraine) to Russian (Russia) appears to solve this.